# Moq Service in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

I have some problem with my unit tests. I want to check that my remove method in service is invoke remove method in repository.

My test method:

```
[Fact]
    public async Task Remove_room_async_should_invoke_remove_room_async_on_room_repository()
    {
        //Arrange
        var room = new Room(Guid.NewGuid(), "A-11");
        var roomRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRoomRepository>();
        var mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
        var roomService = new RoomService(roomRepositoryMock.Object, mapperMock.Object);

        //Act
        await roomService.RemoveAsync(room.RoomId);

        //Assert
        roomRepositoryMock.Verify(x => x.RemoveAsync(It.IsAny<Room>()), Times.Once());
    }
```

Currently it return me FAIL with exception becouse room with this id doesn't exist.

My repository remove method implementation:

```
public async Task RemoveAsync(Room room)
{
    _rooms.Remove(room);
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

And service

```
public async Task RemoveAsync(Guid roomId)
{
    var room = await _roomRepository.GetOrFailAsync(roomId);
    await _roomRepository.RemoveAsync(room);
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't actually `Add()` anything using `roomService`, why would it be able to `Remove()`?

Comment: You will have to Mock 'GetOrFailAsync' method also in the Unit test and return a 'Room' entity from it to be removed.

Comment: GetOrFailAsync is extension method. Can I Mock it? I done this: ` roomRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(room.RoomId)).ReturnsAsync(room); ` at it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the GetOrFailAsync method on your mock IRoomRepository, otherwise the mock is not going to return anything.

So your arrange section becomes:

```
var room = new Room(Guid.NewGuid(), "A-11");
var roomRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRoomRepository>();
roomRepositoryMock.Setup(r => r.GetOrFailAsync).Returns(room);
var mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
var roomService = new RoomService(roomRepositoryMock.Object, mapperMock.Object);
```

You also probably want to verify this call as well:

```
roomRepositoryMock.Verify(r => r.GetOrFailAsync(room.Id), Times.Once());
```

And consider changing your other verification to match exactly the room you want to delete, rather than IsAny:

```
roomRepositoryMock.Verify(x => x.RemoveAsync(room), Times.Once());
```

Comment: Thank for reaply, but i can't Setup and Verify GetOrFailAsync becouse it's extension method and throws exception: `System.NotSupportedException : Invalid verify on an extension method: x => x.GetOrFailAsync(.room.RoomId)` but I can verify my `GetAsync` method

Comment: Why are you using an extension method? Could you change your design to remove the extension method? Otherwise you won't be able to mock that method using Moq.

Comment: I'm learning programming and I wanted to learn how to use extension methods to throw exceptions. I'm going to implement my own middleware if extension methods are not good way :).